# Converting enum class to Json and adding a key in Java

Tags: java, json

I have been trying to convert an enum class containing some values to Json Object.

Till now i have done following:

```
public class ExpertiseService {

    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
     JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    public String getAllExpertise() throws JsonProcessingException, JSONException{
        ExpertiseCategory[] expertiseArray = ExpertiseCategory.values();
        obj.put("expertise",Arrays.toString(expertiseArray));
        return obj.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ExpertiseService obj = new ExpertiseService();
        try {
            System.out.println(obj.getAllExpertise());
        } catch (JsonProcessingException | JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{"expertise":"[SALES, SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT, BUSINESS_OPERATIONS]"}
```

But i want the output to come as

```
{"expertise":["SALES","SOFTWARE_DEVELOPMENT", "BUSINESS_OPERATIONS"]}
```

Comment: You have `Arrays.toString` giving you a string, but instead you want to have a JSON array. You can create a JSON array using your `mapper`.

Comment: I tried that but it gave me "\" in the beginning and end of every value

Comment: Show us what exactly you tried.

Comment: i used ObjectMapper  insead of this  obj.put("expertise",Arrays.toString(expertiseArray));                                        i did this  obj.put("expertise",objectMapper.writeValueAsString(expertiseArray) );

Comment: There should be a method "create array" (or similar) offered by `mapper`. Please try to understand the difference between a String and a real array object.